# Mongolite Showing No Data After Connecting to MongoDB

Tags: r, mongodb, rstudio, mongolite

I'm pretty novice with Mongolite, and I'm trying to query my database which is server side. However, I'm running into an issue that all of my queries are returning no data.

To connect, I run the following code:

```
con <- mongo(db="terrain", url="mongodb://22.92.59.149:27017")
```

After that, I run the following code, and get this output:

```
con$count('{}')
0
con$find('{}')
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

When I export the database from the command line as a csv, it exports the exact same file that was imported via command line, so as far as I can tell it is on my end. Additionally, I believe I am looking in the correct location because when I listCollections, I get a list of all of the databases:

```
admin <- mongo(db="admin", url="mongodb://22.92.59.149:27017")
admin$run('{"listDatabases":1}')
```

This segment of code outputs a list of all of the databases, their size on the disc, and whether they are empty or not. This is the same result if you query the DB names from the command line.

What am I missing here? I'm sure its something very simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The collection argument defaults to "test", so your `mongo` object is currently looking for a collection called "test" inside your "terrain" database. Is this intended?

Comment: The way I understand MongoDB works is that there are collections, and those are called "test" by default. Then, inside of collections there are databases. From what I can tell, when we ran the admin$run command that spit out the list of databases, there were 7 databases inside the test collection. So if I specify the database as one of those 7, and it falls inside the default test collection, it should work.

Comment: A database contains many collections.

Comment: If I try it the other way around with collection="terrain" instead of db="terrain", I have the same issue.

Comment: What is your database called, and which collection inside it are you trying to access?

Comment: Figured it out! I thought that it had been creating the mongodb in the "test" collection, but it had a different name.

On a side note, is there a command to identify the available collections at a given URI?

Comment: "I thought that it had been creating the mongodb in the "test" collection" - you still sound confused. A mongodb instance contains databases. A database contains collections, and a collection contains documents.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I identify what collections exist inside of a database? For example, if I don't know what collections exist inside the "terrain" database, how can I output those using Mongolite?

Comment: see [this discussion](https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite/issues/86) on the mongolite github for the answers